# Can I run the 'min' task twice in Grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Is there a way to run a task twice with different configurations in Grunt? Let's say I have two sets of source files in my project and I want to minify them into two separate, minified output files. Like this:

```
project
    srcA
        fileA1.js
        fileA2.js
    srcB
        fileB1.js
        fileB2.js
```

As the expected result, I would like to see `fileA.min.js` and `fileB.min.js`. How can I achieve that, as `min` only seems to support one set of `src` and `dest` attributes?

```
min: {
  dist: {
    src: [  'srcA/*.js'],
    dest: 'fileA.min.js'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure
in config object you should configure two min tasks

```
min: {
  a_file: {
    src : [/* a src */],
    dest : "path_to_a_file"
  },
  b_file: {
    src : [/* b src */],
    dest : "path_to_b_file"
  }
}
```

After that you can create or rewrite default task or even add it to your custom task:

```
grunt.registerTask('minify', ['min:a_file', 'min:b_file'])
//or 
grunt.registerTask('build', ['concat', 'min:a_file', 'min:b_file'])
```

And now you can run tasks:

```
grunt minify
grunt build
```